# How to perform a query when a button is clicked in this legacy php web app?

Tags: php

I am totaly new in **PHP** and I have the following problem implementing a change request on a very old legacy web application (so I can't change the used logic).

I have this php file used to show a popup:

```
<?php
require_once("../../../common/lib.php");
require_once("../../../common/define.php");

if(isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_SESSION['user']['id'])){
    $id_booking = (int)$_POST['id'];
    if(is_numeric($id_booking)){ ?>
        <script>
            function printElem(elem){
                var popup = window.open('', 'print', 'height=800,width=600');
                popup.document.write('<html><head><title>'+document.title+'</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo getFromTemplate("css/print.css"); ?>"/></head><body>'+document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML+'</body></html>');
                setInterval(function(){
                    popup.document.close();
                    popup.focus();
                    popup.print();
                    popup.close();
                }, 100);
                return true;
            }
        </script>

    <div class="white-popup-block" id="popup-booking-<?php echo $id_booking; ?>">

        <h2><?php echo $texts['CANCEL_BOOKING'] ?></h2>

        <p>Sei veramente sicuro di voler cancellare la prenotazione?</p>
        <?php echo $id_booking; ?>


        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary sendAjaxForm" data-action="/perform_query">
            <i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>
            Conferma
        </a>

        <?php
            $result_remove_booking = $db->query("UPDATE pm_booking SET status= ".$id_booking);
        ?>

    </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>

    <?php
}
?>
```

As you can see it contains a confirmation "button", this one:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary sendAjaxForm" data-action="/perform_query">
    <i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> 
    Conferma
</a>
```

I want implement the feature that when this button is clicked the following defined query is perfromed, this one:

```
<?php
    $result_remove_booking = $db->query("UPDATE pm_booking SET status= ".$id_booking);
?>
```

After that this operation is executed the popup have to be closed.

How can I correctly perform my query when this button is clicked?

Comment: Is there already some javascript that you haven't provided that does the ajax?  I'm guessing an event handler on the class "sendAjaxForm"?  Can you show that code as well.

Comment: @RyanTuosto this can be done also in some other way...I can remove the sendAjaxForm and do it in PHP. Can I do in this way?

Comment: Yes you would need to wrap the <a> with a <form action="/perform_query"> and change the <a> to <button type="submit">

Comment: Or, the php behind the ajax call should perform the query.

Comment: Also the PHP that does the query should be on the perform_query page, not on this page... it looks like its updating pm_booking every time you load the page... and furthermore its updating every row in pm_booking!!!!  So be careful.  Your update almost definitley needs "WHERE id = $id_booking" but you also need to protect yourself from sql injection.  You are vulnerable now.

Comment: @RyanTuosto but in this way it go on the "/perform_query.php" file, is it? Is this page rendered?

Comment: at the end of /perform_query.php you can redirect back to the page you want to render with header("Location: path/to/somepage.php");